# 2x Navigation bar Android

Tags: android, fragment, navigationbar

I hope you will be gentle to me, as i am new at programming in android.

I'm working on a project, where i need 2 navigation bars. For start i have added the navigation bar template, where i can access it by swiping from left to right. The navigation bar works, and i can change fragment based on what item i click on the navigation bar.

**Template Navigation bar**

[image: Template Navigation bar]

But then i also need another navigation bar at the bottom of the screen. A navigation bar which is always visible.

**Bottom Navigation bar**

[image: Bottom Navigation bar]

The layout is as it's supposed to be, from what i can see in code, but when i enter it in the onNavigationItemSelected, made from the template, nothing happens when i click on the items at bottom navigation bar.

```
 @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_startside) {
        // Handle the startside

        Toast.makeText( this, "Startside", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

        //telefonSensor();

        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace( R.id.flMain, new StartsideFragment() );
        ft.commit();

        // onImageGalleryClicked();

    } else if (id == R.id.bot_home) {

        Toast.makeText( this, "Startside", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

        //telefonSensor();

        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace( R.id.flMain, new StartsideFragment() );
        ft.commit();


    } else if (id == R.id.nav_projektkonfiguration) {

        Toast.makeText( this, "Projekt Konfiguration", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace( R.id.flMain, new ProjektKonfigurationFragment() );
        ft.commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_tabel) {

        Toast.makeText( this, "Data Tabel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace( R.id.flMain, new DataTabelFragment() );
        ft.commit();


        //idFrag = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.idTX );

        //idFrag.setText("Hej");

        System.out.println( "DET ER HER DU SKAL KIGGE LIGE NU YUSUF" );

    } else if (id == R.id.bot_dashboard) {

        Toast.makeText( this, "Data Tabel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace( R.id.flMain, new DataTabelFragment() );
        ft.commit();


        //idFrag = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.idTX );

        //idFrag.setText("Hej");

        System.out.println( "DET ER HER DU SKAL KIGGE LIGE NU YUSUF" );

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_plot) {

        Toast.makeText( this, "Data Plot", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace( R.id.flMain, new DataPlotFragment() );
        ft.commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_sensoroversigt) {

        Toast.makeText( this, "Sensor Oversigt", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace( R.id.flMain, new SensorOversigtFragment() );
        ft.commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_registrersensor) {

        Toast.makeText( this, "Tilføj Sensor", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace( R.id.flMain, new TilfojSensorFragment() );
        ft.commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_kontakt) {

        Toast.makeText( this, "Kontakt os her", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace( R.id.flMain, new KontaktFragment() );
        ft.commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.bot_kontakt) {

        Toast.makeText( this, "Kontakt os her", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace( R.id.flMain, new KontaktFragment() );
        ft.commit();


    } else if (id == R.id.nav_logud) {

        firebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();

        Toast.makeText( this, "You're succesfully logged out", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

        Intent intent = new Intent( this, LoginActivity.class );

        startActivity( intent );

        //  login();


    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById( R.id.drawer_layout );
    drawer.closeDrawer( GravityCompat.START );
    return true;
}
```

- bot_home
- bot_dashboard
- bot_kontakt

Above id's are from the bottom navigation bar. Question is of course, how do i code, so that when i click on these items on the bottom navigation bar, then it changes fragment. Do i have to code a new "onNavigationItemSelected". I don't expect thats the answer. I hope you have the answer!

Thanks in advance!

*** UPDATE ***

in my onCreate i have this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );

    onCreate2();

    final android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    BottomNavigationView mBottomNav = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById( R.id.nav_bot );

    mBottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener( new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {

                case R.id.bot_home:

                    //Toast.makeText( this, "Startside", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

                    //telefonSensor();

                    fragment = new StartsideFragment();
                    /*ft.replace( R.id.flMain, new StartsideFragment() );
                    ft.commit();*/

                    break;

                case R.id.bot_dashboard:
                    //Toast.makeText( this, "Startside", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

                    //telefonSensor();

                    //android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragment = new DataTabelFragment();
                    //ft.replace( R.id.flMain, new DataTabelFragment() );
                    //ft.commit();

                    //fragment = new DataTabelFragment();
                    break;

                case R.id.bot_kontakt:

                    //Toast.makeText( this, "Startside", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

                    //telefonSensor();

                    //android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    /*ft.replace( R.id.flMain, new KontaktFragment() );
                    ft.commit();*/
                    break;


            }

            if (fragment != null) {

                //FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.replace( R.id.flMain, fragment );
                ft.commit();

            }

            return true;
        }

    } );


}
```

but then i can only use the bottom navigation bar once before it crashes

LogCat:

```
09-24 14:57:47.304 2954-2954/com.example.yusuf.cxweb E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.yusuf.cxweb, PID: 2954
java.lang.IllegalStateException: commit already called
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:666)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:634)
    at com.example.yusuf.cxweb.MainActivity$1.onNavigationItemSelected(MainActivity.java:360)
    at android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView$1.onMenuItemSelected(BottomNavigationView.java:182)
    at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:822)
    at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:171)
    at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:973)
    at android.support.design.internal.BottomNavigationMenuView$1.onClick(BottomNavigationMenuView.java:95)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Comment: Yes, but not the same:

- Template Navigation bar -> activity_main_drawer.xml
 & Bottom Navigation bar -> navigation.xml

Comment: You must use onBottomNavigationItemSelector, Check out my answer below.

Comment: you have to create different navigation item selected listener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your layout xml file should have attributes like below:

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        .......
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_items"/>
```

and there is a menu resource file like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_startside"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_account_box_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/item_1"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_plot"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_account_circle_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/item_2"/>
    ......
</menu>
```

If you have already above files, maybe you forget register event listener like this:

```
 BottomNavigationView mBottomNav= (BottomNavigationView)findViewById(R.id.navigation);                
 mBottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                    // handle desired action here             
                    return true;
                }
            });

**Edited**
```

Try this:

```
Fragment fragment = null;


switch (viewId) {
    case R.id.bot_home:
        fragment = new StartsideFragment();    
        break;
    case R.id.bot_dashboard:
        fragment = new DataTabelFragment();        
        break;

}

if (fragment != null) {
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.flMain, fragment);
    ft.commit();
}
```

**Updated**

```
if (fragment != null) {

     FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
     ft.replace( R.id.flMain, fragment );
     ft.commit();

 }
```

and delete this:

```
 final android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Please, if you have time, read my update in my question, as it evolved into another problem now!

Comment: I've tried this , but it keeps crashing, when doing this

Comment: any logcat info?

Comment: Yes, just edited my Question update. Should be there

Comment: it works now. I am an idiot. I had the "FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();" outside the if loop and switch. Thanks alot man

Comment: @Buster3650 you are welcome,could you upvote or accept my answer, thanks!

Comment: It's already done! It's recorded, but not shown in here! (Too few reputation)

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

Write this in `onCreate()`:

```
private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.your_id:

                 Class fragmentClass;
                 Fragment fragment;     

                 fragmentClass = StartsideFragment.class;     

                 try { 
                     fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
                 }
                 catch(Exception e) {
                 }
                 fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                 fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

                 drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
                 drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);         

                 break:

            case R.id.your_id:
                 ..... (Your Fragment Code)
                 break:
            }
       return true;
       }
 }
```

Try it. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Please, if you have time, read my update in my question, as it evolved into another problem now!

Comment: @Buster3650 Check my updated answer,  This is how I'm doing it in my project.